# A problem occurred evaluating project ':media_kit_libs_android_video'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\media_kit_libs_android_video-1.0.0\android\build.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':media_kit_libs_android_video'.

> github.com

Answer (score 0):

Go

> C:\Users\YourPC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\

and just delete **media_kit_libs_android_video-1.0.0**.

Comment: You should look at the question carefully. What you say is that you are asking the host to delete his own project.